# DrEdit Java App of Google App Engine gives 500 Server while deploying

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to bring up DrEdit Java App. I followed all the instructions provided in the following link https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/java to bring it up.

From eclipse, once I start "Deploy the app", eclipse says building and deployed the app successfully but on the browser end, it asks for authentication, once I tell accept I am
getting 500 server error

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

Can somebody suggest where I have gone wrong, and how to solve this problem.

Thanks
lakshmi

Comment: Is there any error trace in the server logs?

Comment: the following is the log message.Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are currently running with version 1.14.1-beta of google-api-client. You need at least version 1.15 of google-api-client to run version 1.16.0-rc of the Google OAuth2 API library.
 at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
 at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:115)
 at com.google.api.services.oauth2.Oauth2.<clinit>(Oauth2.java:48)

Comment: The exception trace is pretty clear. If you need the Google OAuth2 API library you need to update the google-api-client.

Comment: yes. i did tried by copying the latest api-client. the dredit source code version started giving coding errors when I updated the api-client. this took me no where.